# sending array from plain php to cakePHP via Header request

Tags: php, cakephp

I have plain php script that doing redirection using Header('Location: ...') and I need to send one array ( 6 keys and 6 value cells with something like 20 characters each) to cakePHP.

I tried to use "session_start()" but by this I cannot connect to session variable.
I cannot use _GET because URL have to be clear.
Maybe the POST is an option but I'm not sure how to send data durring Header request.

Comment: session? database? What have you tried so far? Why is $_GET not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arr = array('this'=>'is', 'some'=>'stuff');
$url = 'someurl.php?vals=' . url_encode(serialize($arr));
header("Location: $url");
```